# What's the meaning of "least" here?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

**least** is superlative of little.

But I'm not sure if it means the same here or not:

> Sergeant Margaret Sorensen, fortyish, stocky, blond hair going gray,
>   always an early riser, is enjoying her Sunday morning coffee at home
>   in her favorite,
>   **least flattering flannel pajamas** when she gets a call from one of the officers at the station.

So could you help me please?

Comment: It is, but it has other meanings too. Did you check a dictionary? [*least*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/least): "6. adverb - 
You use **least** to indicate that someone or something has less of a particular quality than most other things of its kind."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Least* modifies *flattering*.

These pajamas flatter the wearer (make the wearer look good) less than any other pajamas she has. This usually is actually used to mean the clothes actually make the wearer look bad rather than good.